# mysql,How to save rounded numbers into longtext field?

Tags: php, mysql

I have done this calculation:

```
$number = round(count($exc)/ count($grades),2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

When save,I have to save it into a field of an existing table which is a longtext type. The numbers got saved but become very long, something like 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125
I think this might cause extra db storage. When I query the numbers, they are still rounded as 2 digital. So, that's an extra converting job. I would like to learn how to save those numbers as rounded number?

Comment: Why would you want to store a **number** as a **longtext** field?

Comment: Why are you using a textual type to store numerical data?  MySQL has a number of numeric datatypes (INT, NUMERIC, FLOAT, etc), why not use one of those?  Using the wrong type for the data you're storing at best robs you of flexibility and at worst will result in incorrect results for SQL operations.  You will not get the items back in the order you expect if you try sorting them, for example

Comment: because I have to save it into an existing table which is not for me to re-design.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP sprintf function coupled with format specifier like so:

```
$number = sprintf("%.3f", round(count($exc)/ count($grades),2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP));
```

If you need more info about that take a look at sprintf PHP documentation here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php .